# Events in Project Explorer Test Comlpite

Tags: testcomplete

I'm new to Test complite, I want use event handling, but in Project Explorer node Events is not displayed. How open this item or what characteristics should have test, so I could see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the Project node in the Project Explorer and select the '**Add | New Item...**' menu item. Select '**Events**' in the 'Create Project Item' dialog and click OK.